# Java JLabel, break text to next line?

Tags: java, swing, text, newline, jlabel

It's been awhile since I asked a question!

I'm developing an application in Java where `JLabels` are used. Anyway, as you may or may not be able to see from the picture below, the text that says `Category Test` gets cut off and ends up saying `Categor...` instead. Is there any way that I can "break" the text once it fills up the width of the label? Here is the image:

[image]

**What I did**

I used a JTextPane like so:

```
    JTextPane text = new JTextPane();
    SimpleAttributeSet attr = new SimpleAttributeSet();   

    StyleConstants.setAlignment(attr, StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);  

    pane.add(text, c);
```

Then I added my text, but thanks anyway!

Comment: I would get the "Category" String out of there. It's completely unnecessary. Instead perhaps have "Categories" in a single JLabel above your grid.

Comment: Uhhh, those are placeholders. The user will define what the categories say. Have you ever seen Jeopardy?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`JLabel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html)s can't do that by default. But `JLabel`s have some support for html, so a `JLabel` with the text `<html>First Line<br />Second Line</html>` would show up on two lines.

If you want a component that can split the lines by itself, take a look at [`JTextArea`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html).

Comment: I'll +1 for now, but I want to see if I can't find another way. Thanks.

Comment: @Ken did more searching, `JLabel`s only display 1 line, unless you use html.

Comment: Do you know **how** I would even put the JTextArea in the JLabel? Do you have some sample code?

Comment: @Ken You would replace the `JLabel` with the `JTextArea`, not put the `JTextArea` inside it.

Answer (score 2):

As I recall, you need to use a JTextArea if you want textwrap.  JLabel doesn't do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can at StyledLabel component from JIDE Common Layer open source project at http://java.net/projects/jide-oss/.

The problem with html JLabel approach is it doesn't auto-wrap and about 20 to 40 times slower than a plain JLabel.

The problem with JTextArea or JTextPane approach is it has a weird size issue and is also 20 times slower.

StyledLabel extends JLabel. Automatically line wrapping is just one of the many features it adds. And the performance is as fast as a plain JLabel.

Hope it will help.